# Data protection / encryption on Azure websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some data to store in a user cookie from a website deployed on Azure.

I tried looking at the DataProtection APIs in System.Security but they all seem to need a machine or user scope, which doesn't work when deployed to Azure.

Then I tried using the AesCryptoServiceProvider and storing the key in my Web.config, but I get this error:

> CryptographicException: The data protection operation was
>   unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile
>   loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case
>   when the thread is impersonating.

I was reading up on the error and apparently you need to tweak an IIS setting, which doesn't work for Azure.

I also tried looking at the DataProtection Asp.NET Core package but it brought in a whole lot of new packages and the docs mentioned needing to store crypto information in a local folder; which again doesn't seem like it would work on Azure without a dedicated machine.

What's the right way to protect/unprotect data on an Azure website?

Comment: Do you mean **only** to protect connection string in web.config?

Comment: @LeiYang No, I'm not talking about anything in web.config. I want to protect an OAuth access token from VSTS and store it as a cookie.

Comment: Why do you think web.config is **dangerous**, in IIS and even in Azure?

Comment: @LeiYang What? When did I say it was dangerous? The question is about encrypting data that's stored in a user cookie. Aes encryption with the key in web.config is just one of the things I looked at. If I ever got that method working I would look into encrypting that section. Don't understand the downvotes here.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I didn't see any relationship of your question with Azure, with IIS, even with asp.net, Your question is only related with C#.

Comment: @LeiYang What is not clear about "I'm trying to encrypt some data to store in a user cookie from a website deployed on Azure." ? Or "What's the right way to protect/unprotect data on an Azure website?" I also EXPLAINED why the standard methods of encrypting and decrypting did not work for me when deployed to Azure, even giving you the exact error message. I mentioned IIS only because the workaround for the error (tweaking an IIS setting) is not available in Azure since you don't have direct control over IIS.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes on this question either.  Is there a reason why you can't just use `AESManaged` to encrypt the token directly in your code?  Store the key in your code if you have to.

Comment: @RandomEngy For specifically encrypting data into cookie you can use the same approach as default Forms auth works like `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` / `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt`; this will use machinekey which you can NOT specify in web.config (so will be used the one generated by azure) or CAN specify in web.config, and then you will need to solve encryption web.config issue (here I don't have any good answer)

Comment: @LukePark Thanks, that worked. It actually turns out I made a mistake and it was only the DataProtection API that was throwing that exception, not `AesCryptoServiceProvider` or `AesManaged` . Will update with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was only the DataProtection API that was throwing the error. `AesManaged` and `AesCryptoServiceProvider` both still work in Azure. Here is what I ended up using:

```
private const string AesKey = "206283c07cbfda1c0c126ef56d78ba9a0aeb53a06cd65f10bd3a9cb9a68e3fe1";

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt)
{
    byte[] encrypted;

    var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.Key = StringToByteArray(AesKey);

    // Create a new IV for each item to encrypt
    aes.GenerateIV();
    byte[] iv = aes.IV;

    using (var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, iv))
    using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            // Prepend unencrypted IV to data
            cipherStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);
            binaryWriter.Write(toEncrypt);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }

        encrypted = cipherStream.ToArray();
    }

    return encrypted;
}

public static byte[] EncryptFromString(string toEncrypt)
{
    return Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt));
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt)
{
    var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.Key = StringToByteArray(AesKey);

    // Pull out the unencrypted IV first
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(toDecrypt, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

    using (var encryptedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedMemoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            // Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
            binaryWriter.Write(
                toDecrypt,
                iv.Length,
                toDecrypt.Length - iv.Length
            );
        }

        return encryptedMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static string DecryptToString(byte[] toDecrypt)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(toDecrypt));
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] array)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(array.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in array)
    {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }

    return hex.ToString();
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    int charCount = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[charCount / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: You have no way of validating the ciphertext here.  You should swap to use GCM mode or add an HMAC.

Comment: @LukePark In my case I don't care if users try to tamper with the data. All it would do is corrupt their token. Though if you care to answer with the GCM or HMAC added on, I'll throw an upvote your way. :)

Comment: Nah.  That's a fair point really.  Just thought you might use the token to validate the user yourself at some point.